# How to use 'AND' condition in 'test' command in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

I am using below command to test the 'AND' condition

```
[[  "$string1" =~ "not" -a ! "$string1" =~ "$chas" ]] && echo "Hello"
```

but it is throwing a syntax error

> -bash: syntax error in conditional expression
>   -bash: syntax error near `-a'

I am not getting what the syntax error here is ...

Individual conditions are working but when using and condition (-a) it is throwing error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) command `[[` is different from `[`. In `[[` `-a file True if file exists.`. Try `&&` for AND bool operator...
But the syntax is a bit different. `=~` means regex pattern matching and the `"` not needed around env vars and regex expression.

So this works for me:

```
[[  $string1 =~ not && ! $string1 =~ $chas ]] && echo "Hello"
```

Comment: oo Nice catch .. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In bash, with `[[`, you can do:

```
[[  "$string1" =~ "not" && ! "$string1" =~ "$chas" ]] && echo "Hello"
```

or

```
[[  "$string1" =~ "not" ]] && [[ ! "$string1" =~ "$chas" ]] && echo "Hello"
```